# Dynamic Radio button store json response id and name in that

Tags: android

Hello guys in bottom I code something which work perfectly but I am using array list in that, but I want Dynamic radio button if user select any button so for user it should display name and for me i get selected id my json response is like divid,divisionname I have to show divisionname to user in Radio button and if user select any radio based on that i want divid any thing if we pass both id and name in one radio button, on submit button i want Id

```
            ArrayList<String> divId = null;
            ArrayList<String> divName = null;
            RadioGroup divRadioGrouop;
            String divsionId=null;

            if (divisionCheck) {
                    RadioButton rdbDiv;
                    divId = new ArrayList<>();
                    divName = new ArrayList<>();
                    divisionLogin.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    divRadioGrouop.removeAllViews();
                    for (int j = 0; j < jsonArrayDiv.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject jsonDiv = jsonArrayDiv.getJSONObject(j);
                        divId.add(jsonDiv.getString("divid"));
                        divName.add(jsonDiv.getString("divisionname"));
                        rdbDiv = new RadioButton(this);
                        rdbDiv.setId(View.generateViewId());
                        rdbDiv.setText(jsonDiv.getString("divisionname"));
                        divRadioGrouop.addView(rdbDiv);
                    }
                    divOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            int divid = divRadioGrouop.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                            RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(divid);

                            String divSionNameFind = (String) radioButton.getText();
                            int idPostionIndex = divName.indexOf(divSionNameFind);
                            divsionId = divId.get(idPostionIndex);
                            divName.clear();
                            divId.clear();

                            logINDataForDiv();

                        }
                    });
                    divCancel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            // do something
                        }
                    });
                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use tag in that case, first add divid in all your radio button like:

```
radioButton.setTag(divid);
```

on Submit, you can get back divid by this:

```
String divid=radioButton.getTag().toString();
```

Make sure you do setTag before getTag, otherwise getTag will return null and your app will crash.